# E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) while doing gitian build

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg, bitcoin

I'm trying to clone Litecoin and build a mock version of it
In order to do that I'm trying to configure gitian builder from this link https://coinaxis.com/index.php/tutorials/entry/how-to-do-a-gitian-build-for-litecoin-tutorial-coinaxis.

When I execute these commands
`sudo bin/make-base-vm -a i386
sudo bin/make-base-vm -a amd64`
this error shoots up
`E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Below is the part of the log for the same:

```
Setting up console-setup (1.108ubuntu15.3) ...
Your console font configuration will be updated the next time your system
boots. If you want to update it now, run 'setupcon' from a virtual console.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu19) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.8) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-87-generic
Processing triggers for resolvconf (1.78ubuntu4) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 sudo
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
W: --force-yes is deprecated, use one of the options starting with --allow                 
instead.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I'm new to this. Kindly help me fix the issue.